# Emacs evil-mode paste encoding

Tags: emacs, evil

I'm using evil-mode with Emacs.

When pasting text with the "+p command (paste from + register) i see sequences of \342\200\231 in text instead of the apostrophe (') character.

The clipboard-yank command works fine. This started happening after evil mode upgrade (to 20140625.411).

What might be the problem here? How can i fix it?

Comment: I don't use `evil-mode`, but I would still probably check things like `set-selection-coding-system`.  The usual suspects relating to encoding include, but are not limited to:  `file-coding-system-alist`; `process-coding-system-alist`; `network-coding-system-alist`; `prefer-coding-system`;  `set-default-coding-systems`; `set-terminal-coding-system`; `set-keyboard-coding-system`; `set-selection-coding-system`; `buffer-file-coding-system`; `x-select-request-type`.  See also my setup in the following link:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20736147/2112489

Comment: Thanks for the config. I've tried it. It doesn't resolve this issue unfortunately. clipboard-paste behaves well, this seems to be connected with evil-mode.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you had any progress?